# django save multiple foreign key values at the same time

Tags: python, django

I have been trying to save a multiple foreign key fields at the same time then I have been getting an error too many times, here is the error

> Exception Value: Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<Assign: Ahmed Nuur : DC :
> Data Communication>, <Assign: Ahmed Nuur : EC : Electrical Circuit>,
> <Assign: Ahmed Nuur : X : ElectricaL>, <Assign: Ahmed Nuur : X :
> ElectricaL>]>": "StudentRegisterCourse.assign" must be a "Assign"
> instance.

if you can help me with that

here is my models.py

```
class StudentRegisterCourse(models.Model):
    assign              = models.ForeignKey(Assign, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    student             = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

and also here is my forms.py

```
class StudentCourseRegistrationForm(ModelForm):
    assign = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        queryset=Assign.objects.all(),
    )
    class Meta:
        model = StudentRegisterCourse
        fields = '__all__'
```

and lastly here is my views.py

```
def staff_student_course_registration(request):
    form = StudentCourseRegistrationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StudentCourseRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            f = form.save(commit=False)
            for ass in f.assign:
                f.assign = ass
                f.student = f.student
                f.save()
            return redirect('staff_student_course_registration')
```

Comment: The error message says that `ass` is a queryset instead of a Assign instance. What is the value of `f.assign` before you loop? And what is the value of `ass`?

Comment: `f.assign` is a form field, so that form field has multiple values that is why I loop it and `ass` is assign instance. That is what I'm thinking. so that is wrong, do you have any idea?